# Move up a line by clicking on it in c#

Tags: c#, draw, paint, move

i want to move up the hand when i click on it and turn right or left the head when i click on head.

please help me and change my source code.

i'm beginner in C#.

download application - C# Vs2008:http://s1.picofile.com/file/7670109244/Move_Hand.rar.html

download link: http://www.freeuploadsite.com/do.php?id=5033

Comment: Your question is very vague and lacks details such as current code, current attempt and may be a visual or what you are trying to achieve. Please add the relavant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the tags to the question - you want to make some kind of vector grapgics editor. Read [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Drawing_Graphics_in_C_Sharp) about how to draw. For manipulating a picture make a class with the which will be responsible for drawing itself then it will asked to, holding the picture info and position. Then add manipulation with handlers (e.g. OnMouseClick and OnMouseMove) which will trigger the change of position and orientation for the pictures -> redraw picture with new position and orientation.

Comment: **I have a user control  and i want to put it on form at run time without drag drop it on form.
my user control name is u1_timer please write for me the code.
c# Programming.**

Comment: If you want someone to write your code, hire him and give him money to do so. But don't beg for it here on SO!

Comment: http://s3.picofile.com/file/7676123866/C_Graphics.rar.html